# What is the difference between SocketAddress and InetAddress in Java

Tags: java

It's unclear what SocketAddres is designed for. As far as I see there is just one reasonable way to use it: through InetSocketAddress. It's confusing.

Comment: Did you read the documentation (and that of relevant sub-classes)? What part of the documentation don't you understand or is confusing you?

Answer (score 3):

InetAddress will give the IP address of specified web site 
example :

```
InetAddress ip=InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");  

System.out.println("Host Name: "+ip.getHostName());  
System.out.println("IP Address: "+ip.getHostAddress());
```

SocketAdress is used to create the Socket at end point with InetAddress and port number

```
 InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
    int port = 80;
    SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(addr, port);

    Socket sock = new Socket();

    sock.connect(sockaddr);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Documentation of `SocketAddress`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/SocketAddress.html):

> This class represents a Socket Address with no protocol attachment. As an abstract class, it is meant to be subclassed with a specific, protocol dependent, implementation.

From the [Documentation of `InetAddress`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html):

> This class represents an Internet Protocol (IP) address.

So one represents a socket without any protocol as abstract class, the other represents an IP-address. What you are most probably looking for is an [`InetSocketAddress`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html) (a socket, bound to a specific IP/Hostname and port).

Comment: To add to what Turing85 says: when many of these networking classes were being defined, there were many different underlying network protocols : decnet, pupnet, and many, many more. They all kind of got steamrollered by the rise of the IP protocol.

So the original socket classes were designed to handle many different kinds of sockets, even though nowadays we just use internet protocol.

(But wait! you should be careful to allow IPv6 -- it's a requirement in many places)

Answer (score 0):

SocketAdress

> This class represents a Socket Address with no protocol attachment. As an abstract class, it is meant to be subclassed with a specific, protocol dependent, implementation.

InetAdress

> This class represents an Internet Protocol (IP) address.

Maybe you want to know about
InetSocketAddress

> This class implements an IP Socket Address (IP address + port number) It can also be a pair (hostname + port number), in which case an attempt will be made to resolve the hostname. If resolution fails then the address is said to be unresolved but can still be used on some circumstances like connecting through a proxy.